# Trying to get number of files total in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I am currently trying read a directory and determine how many files total are in each of its top level directory, including each of their subdirectory. The "folders check scan" function is supposed to reach further down into subdirectories and count the files in each by calling itself, but it only counts the files in the first level of subdirectories. Is there something I am missing?

```
import os
import csv

def folders_check_scan(value):
    count = 0
    for y in os.scandir(value):
        if y.is_dir():
            folders_check_scan(y)
        elif y.is_file():
            count += 1
            
    return count



#function that takes summary of what is in repository
def list_files(startpath):
    #get number of folders in the first level of this directory
    print(len(next(os.walk(startpath))[1]))

    #gets top level folders in directory
    directory = next(os.walk(startpath))[1]
    print(startpath)
    directory_path = []
    for b in directory:
        newline = startpath + "\\" + b
        directory_path.append(newline)

    #call function to take record of number of files total in directory
    for x in directory_path:
        count = folders_check_scan(x)
        print(x)
        print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't storing the result of the recursive call:

```
        if y.is_dir():
            count += folders_check_scan(y)
        elif y.is_file():
            count += 1
```

Comment: That was the answer! Thank you so much Zev!